# Rails turbo_stream replace options_from_collection_for_select from turbo_stream.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, stimulusjs, hotwire-rails, turbo

I'm trying to replace the value of the dropdown though the turbo stream.

through js request we can do as

views/projects/filter_units_by_organization.js.erb

```
$('select#project_unit_id').html('<%= j options_from_collection_for_select(@filtered_units, :id, :name) %>');
```

for turbo the file is as

views/projects/filter_units_by_organization.turbo_stream.erb

```
<%= turbo_stream.replace "option" do %>
 
<% end %>
```

views/projects/_form.html.erb

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :organization_id %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select :organization_id, Organization.all, :id, :name, { prompt: 'Please select' } %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :unit_id %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select :unit_id, Unit.all.where(organization_id: :organization_id), :id, :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
```

I am trying to use a similar approach in the case of turbo stream.
Turbo is replacing the complete div, is it possible to replace the select tag only?

## Solution

```
<%= turbo_stream.update "project_unit_id" do 
  options_from_collection_for_select(@objects, :id, :name) %>
<% end %>
```

if you want to add include blank value then use

```
<%= turbo_stream.update 'project_unit_id' do %>
  <%= options_for_select(@objects.collect{ |obj| [obj.name, obj.id] }.unshift(['Select Value', nil])) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `turbo_stream.update("project_unit_id") { options_from_collection_for_select(...) }`

Comment: Thanks, Alex, it worked.
I was near to it but not able to figure it out correctly.

Comment: Thanks so much for providing your answer! Been looking for a way to use Hotwire for this and could not figure it out till now.